# How to add a Reset Button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add a reset button in a counter app, but I got stuck, can someone help me?

```js
let mainNum = document.querySelector(".numbers").textContent;
document.querySelector(".more").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  mainNum++;
  document.querySelector(".mainNum").textContent = mainNum;
});

document.querySelector(".less").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  mainNum--;
  document.querySelector(".mainNum").textContent = mainNum;
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="numbers">
  <div class="mainNum">10</div>
</div>

<div class="moreButton">
  <button class="more"><i class="fas fa-arrow-up fa-Bx"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain the problem a little more, please?

Comment: Hi @MuratColyaran, thank you for your goodwill on this, but I think my code is running now, however, I dunno how hehehehe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a button and when the user clicks the `reset` button then reset the counter to its default value i.e. `10` in your case.

```js
let mainNum = document.querySelector(".numbers").textContent;
document.querySelector(".more").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  mainNum++;
  document.querySelector(".mainNum").textContent = mainNum;
});

document.querySelector(".less").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  mainNum--;
  document.querySelector(".mainNum").textContent = mainNum;
});

document.querySelector(".reset").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  mainNum = 10;
  document.querySelector(".mainNum").textContent = mainNum;
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div class="numbers">
  <div class="mainNum">10</div>
</div>

<div class="moreButton">
  <button class="more"><i class="fas fa-arrow-up fa-Bx"></i></button>
  <button class="less"><i class="fas fa-arrow-down fa-Bx"></i></button>
  <button class="reset">reset</button>
</div>
```

Comment: accept the answer, if you think it worked for you

Comment: I'm not sure how to, could you please guide me on how?